# ¿Cómo puedo transformar lista a diccionario concatenenado valores de lista en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo esa lista que quiero pasar a diccionario dejando como clave el elemento que comienza con nota y como valor los elementos que siguen a nota en el orden de la lista

```
lista = ["notas_a", "n1","n2","n3","n4", "notas_b","n2","n34","n5","notas_z","notas_c","n3","n4","n55"]
```

y quiero obtener algo como esto:

```
diccionario = {"notas_a":['n1 n2 n3 n4'], "notas_b":['n2 n34 n5'], "notas_z":None, "notas_c":['n3 n4 n55']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es recorrer la lista. Al encontrar una palabra que comienza con "notas_", agregar una entrada al diccionario bajo esa palabra. Su contenido será una lista vacía.

Si la palabra no comienza con "notas_", la agregamos a la último entrada del diccionario. Esta entrada la guardamos en la variable `entrada` para simplificar su acceso.

Aqui el truco está en reconocer que `entrada` y `dic[palabra]` son dos nombres diferentes para la misma cosa; si modifico uno, el otro también se ve afectado.

```
lista = ["notas_a", "n1","n2","n3","n4", "notas_b","n2","n34","n5","notas_z","notas_c","n3","n4","n55"]
dic = {}
entrada = None
for palabra in lista:
    if palabra[:6] == "notas_":
        dic[palabra] = []
        entrada = dic[palabra]
    else:
        entrada.append(palabra)

print(dic)
```

produce:

```
{'notas_a': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'], 'notas_b': ['n2', 'n34', 'n5'], 'notas_z': [], 'notas_c': ['n3', 'n4', 'n55']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve buscando una forma más sencilla de hacerlo, pero no la encontré. Esta es la manera en la que yo lo haría:

```
lista = ["notas_a", "n1","n2","n3","n4", "notas_b","n2","n34","n5","notas_z","notas_c","n3","n4","n55"]

diccionario = {}
for elemento in lista:
    if "notas" in elemento: # Si el elemento contiene la palabra notas es reconocido como key
        key = elemento
        value = ""
        primeraVez = True
    else:
        if primeraVez: # Control necesario para evitar que todos los valores inicien con un espacio ej: ' n2 n34 n5'
            value = elemento 
            primeraVez = False
        else:
            value += " " + elemento # Coloca todos los valores diferentes a 'notas' en value separandolos con un espacio
    diccionario.update({key: value}) # Añade los diccionarios
```

Devuelve:

```
{"notas_a":"n1 n2 n3 n4", "notas_b":"n2 n34 n5", "notas_z":"", "notas_c":"n3 n4 n55"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mirando con detenimiento tu pregunta, veo que lo que buscabas obtener al final resulta un poco extraño. ¿Quieres que cada elemento del diccionario sea una lista pero que cada una de esas listas contenga un solo elemento que sea una cadena en la que aparezcan concatenados todos los valores?

Es un requisito bastante raro, y asumo que en realidad lo que quieres es que cada elemento del diccionario sea una lista de cadenas (una lista que podría estar vacía).

Si es esto último, la respuesta de Candid Moe es válida, y también esta otra que hace esencialmente lo mismo pero sin usar la variable intermedia `entrada`. En vez de ello guardo en `clave` el valor de la palabra que está actuando como clave, y se cambia cada vez que aparece una nueva palabra que comienza por "notas".

```
dic = {}
clave = None
for palabra in lista:
    if palabra.startswith("nota"):
      clave = palabra
      dic[clave] = []
    else:
      dic[clave].append(palabra)
```

Pero si realmente lo que buscas es lo que has enunciado en la pregunta, es posible a continuación convertir el diccionario resultante del código anterior en el diccionario que tú quieres, mediante una *comprensión de diccionarios*, que incluye además una *expresión condicional* para tratar de forma especial el caso con la lista vacía:

```
resultado = {k: [" ".join(v) ] if v else None for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Con los datos de entrada de tu pregunta el resultado es:

```
{'notas_a': ['n1 n2 n3 n4'], 'notas_b': ['n2 n34 n5'], 'notas_z': None, 'notas_c': ['n3 n4 n55']}
```